# Installing driver for AMD RX 590 with AMD Ryzen 2400G results in Error 1603

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, gpu

I have the following system:

- AMD Ryzen 2400G
- Gigabyte Mainboard (support for AMD Ryzen 2400G)
- 8 GB RAM
- Later: AMD RX 590

I installed all the driver for the integrated GPU of my AMD Ryzen 2400G and everything worked fine. I played a couple of games but after sometime I noticed that I would like to have a better GPU and bought the new AMD RX 590. I put that GPU in my PC and connected my display to the GPU instead of the mainboard. But then the problem began...

I downloaded the latest driver for the RX 590 from AMDs website (since the vendor of my RX 590 does not offer their own/redirects to AMD). But every single time the installation results in error 1603. I therefore went through the AMD article about this [issue](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-kb1603)  and did every single step. After some time I was so frustrated that I reinstalled my windows completely, but even then with nothing else installed the driver would fail. The weird thing is that after the installation fails I can update the driver via the device manager and windows then finds the driver for the RX 590. But then my system breaks with a windows update for AMD drivers. I also tried several other things that I don't remember and currently waiting for the response of the AMD support.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I am not able to find the root cause for this issue I came up with the following solution:

Disable the integrated GPU of the AMD Ryzen 2400G via the BIOS and restart the system. After the restart I am able to open up the AMD settings and everything seems fine. I didn't have to reinstall the driver again, everything was there in the latest version.

The only thing which not yet perfect is that even though the AMD Ryzen 2400G GPU is disabled, the system can only use 6,95 GB of RAM. Shouldn't this be something like 7.x? But that's another question, for now the system runs well. It seems like an AMD driver issue if you using an integrated and a dedicated GPU at the same time.